# Why does my android studio not see my gradle file?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

**I'm getting error=
ERROR:**

```
Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Comment: Screenshots are often not helpful when looking at the structure of code. Post the general structure of your project and specifically mention where you tried to add the `build.gradle` file and mention the error provided by `Android Studio`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing android plugin definition in your gradle. Put this line at top in your gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Also make sure you are using gradle version above 3.0 and have following repositories added in gradle. Try clean and build after you update your gradle.

```
repositories {
   google()
   jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'" from build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {

 //  .......
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'//remove this line 

 //.......
 }
```

**OR**

add this line at the end of build.gradle file

```
 repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem which is occurring in your `build.gradle(app)`, has the solution. You just remove all the **testImplementation and androidTestImplementation** from your **dependencies**. I guess you won't find any issues from there onwards. Usually in the **app build.gradle** only **implementations** of the libraries should be there. Go ahead and do it, tell me what you get after that.

```
dependencies{
   implementation
   // comment or remove all the testCompilations and androidTestCompilations and sync the gradle
   //add this at the end of the line, this is for compilation of the gradle
   annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

I hope it helps.